# Csv file tokenization using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I can't find any example coding about how to do tokenization with csv file using Pandas Python. Below is my code with the cleaned review. I am going to use this "cleaned_review" to perform tokenization.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9mLv.png)

Answer (score 0):

to perform tokenization on cleaned_review, apply the NLTK word tokenizer row-wise to the column.

```
import nltk
steam_reviews['cleaned_review'] = steam_reviews.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['cleaned_review']), axis=1)
```